# Dynamic Remove Function

Tags: c#

I have the following code that works but would like a more reusable was or getting the same results. Rather than a `Remove_At_Weight` and a `Remove_At_Code` function I would like a generic `Remove` function that you can choose which field to compare and what to compare it against.

So for example I might have another object called say `Recordo_3` which has a third field 
"String  Description" 
and I want to check this field with out having to write a new "Remove_At_Description" function.

I am probably approaching this from the wrong angle and there is a better way of doing it using a design patten etc. if so please advise. Hope this makes sense.

```
class Recordo
{
    private string _code;

    public string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set { _code = value; }
    }
    private int _weight;

    public int Weight
    {
        get { return _weight; }
        set { _weight = value; }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Recordo> lr = new List<Recordo>();

    lr.Add(new Recordo() {Code = "QQQ", Weight = 10});
    lr.Add(new Recordo() { Code = "AAA", Weight = 20 });
    lr.Add(new Recordo() { Code = "AAA", Weight = 10 });
    lr.Add(new Recordo() { Code = "QQQ", Weight = 10 });            

    lr = Remove_At_Code(lr,"QQQ");
    lr = Remove_At_Weight(r, "20");
    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}

private static List<Recordo> Remove_At_Weight(List<Recordo> lr, int weight)
{
    for (int i = lr.Count-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (lr[i].Weight == weight)
        {
            lr.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    return lr;
}

private static List<Recordo> Remove_At_Code(List<Recordo> lr, string code)
{
    for (int i = lr.Count-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (lr[i].Code == code)
        {
            lr.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    return lr;
}
```

Comment: What about using the IComperable interface? - google it

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann IComparable isn't required. I guess you meant IEquatable

Comment: @Sriram both would work

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann Both would work but `IComparable` isn't needed as it is primarily for sorting not for testing its equality

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yep, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's do it without a generic method which you have asked for (for that you might consider reflection with property name - **see below**). Your work can be done in a very simple way using `Linq` like this

```
lr.RemoveAll(r => r.Code.Equals("QQQ")); 
lr.RemoveAll(r => r.Weight == 20);
```

**Now** if you really want that generic method, you can try this

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static void RemoveAllWithPropertyValue<T>(this List<T> list, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        list.RemoveAll(item => property.GetValue(item, null).Equals(value));
    }
}
```

And use this custom extension as

```
lr.RemoveAllWithPropertyValue("Code", "QQQ");
lr.RemoveAllWithPropertyValue("Weight", 20);
```

*Note: This is not type-safe, and we didn't do any validation!*

Comment: I knew I would be over complicating it, Thanks very much for this worked a treat.

Comment: @user3755946 Yeah, it's really that simple! And for your curiosity, check out the generic method as well. Not 'perfect', but will work just fine for you :)

Comment: Hi just going through the Generic Method just now, this seems Ideal. Excuse my ignorance but when you say type safe i take it you mean the IDE will not know that Code and Weight etc. are valid i.e. if miss typed you would get an error. Also what do you mean by Validation?  is this something should be concerned about.   The real Application has a much bigger record and polls a SQL DB every 3 min displaying stock levels. I play on making similar apps with different Query hence the desire for a generic method.  Thanks for you time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Matthias Herrmann said You could use ICompareable interface, but to be honest this task is so easy that You can achieve it with one easy linq query. For instance:

```
var theList = new List<Recordo>(); // lets assume it already have some records
var someCode = "QQQ";
var someWeight = 15;

theList.RemoveRange(theList.Where(x => x.Code == someCode));
//OR the following for weight
theList.RemoveRange(theList.Where(x => x.Weight == someWeight ));
```

Comment: @MajkeloDev I think your solution is the best one for this case. If there is a databinding to this list I guess the best thing is to use the ObservableCollection(T)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [List.RemoveAll Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) for that

```
lr.RemoveAll(item => item.Code == "QQQ");
lr.RemoveAll(item => item.Weight == 20);
```

You don't need own generic function because the method mentioned does just that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler to just use LINQ:

This would get all of the items where the Weight is not 7.

```
lr = lr.Where( item => item.Weight != 7 ).ToList();
```

Or, if you wanted to keep it more like your original code:

You could pass in a function

And call it like this:

```
lr = GenericRemove( lr, item => item.Weight == 7  );


private static List<Recordo> GenericRemove(List<Recordo> lr, Func<Recordo, bool> filter)
{
       for (int i = lr.Count-1; i > -1; i--)
        {

            if ( filter( lr[i]) )
            {
                lr.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        return lr;
}
```